# How do I count the rows that are not empty with GROUP BY in Python's SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, group-by

I'm using the standard SQLite3 in Python 3.6. I want to count for each `group_num` how many of the rows have an entry for `list_num` that's not empty. Empty meaning either an empty string or NULL.

I currently group with:

```
SELECT group_num, count(list_num)  
FROM pair_candidates WHERE list_num IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY group_num
```

This counts how many rows have the same `group_num` but unfortunatley it doesn't tell me about how much of those rows have a `list_num` that's not empty.

I tried adding `WHERE list_num IS NOT NULL` before the GROUP BY clause and that doesn't help. Trying `HAVING list_num IS NOT NULL` after the GROUP BY also didn't help.

What do I need to do to get my counts?

Example:

```
group_num | list_num
----------+---------
1         | 
1         | 1
2         | 1
2         | 1
3         | ""
3         |
```

I want to get

```
group_num | count
----------+------
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 0
```

Comment: how about `Select group_num, count(list_num)  
FROM (SELECT * FROM pair_candidates WHERE list_num IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY group_num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select rows having *list_num* not equal to an empty string. Because comparisons with NULL produce UNKNOWN, those rows will be discarded as well:

```
SELECT group_num, COUNT(*)
FROM pair_candidates
WHERE list_num != ''
GROUP BY group_num
```

But that will not produce results for *group_num* having no rows matching the criteria, so the results are not exactly what you hoped for. In order to produce a count for the "empty" groups as well you can use the fact that [`COUNT(X)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count) returns the number of times X is not NULL in a group.

```
SELECT group_num, COUNT(NULLIF(list_num, ''))
FROM pair_candidates
GROUP BY group_num
```

[`NULLIF(X, Y)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif) returns its first argument if the arguments are different, NULL if they are same, so `COUNT(NULLIF(X, ''))` does not count if X is `''`.

A full example:

```
In [1]: from contextlib import closing

In [2]: import sqlite3

In [3]: conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

In [4]: with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
   ...:     cur.execute('create table pair_candidates (group_num, list_num)')
   ...:     cur.executemany('insert into pair_candidates values (?, ?)', [
   ...:         (1, None), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 1), (3, ""), (3, None)])
   ...:         

In [5]: with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
   ...:     cur.execute('''select group_num, count(nullif(list_num, ''))
   ...:                    from pair_candidates
   ...:                    group by group_num''')
   ...:     res = cur.fetchall()
   ...:     

In [6]: res
Out[6]: [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot obtain it simply from a SQL query. NULL is a special animal that can only be caught by `IS NULL` and is definitely not the same as `""`. But that is not all: `SELECT COUNT GROUP BY` will never return a line with 0 as count, but will simply return no line for that group. After all, no line were returned by the query for that group, and count is only an aggregate *on returned lines*.

It is certainly possible to use external joins to force a line in resulting set, but it will certainly be rather complex unless you are really proficient in SQL. But it is trivial to mix 2 queries from Python code: first returns the list of groups and initializes the count to 0, the second one returns the non zero count and can be used to update the initial mapping.

Assuming `con` is an active connection to a Sqlite3 database, you can do:

```
groups = { x[0]: 0 for x in con.execute(
    "SELECT distinct group_num FROM pair_candidates").fetchall() }
groups.update({ x[0]: x[1] for x in con.execute(
    """SELECT group_num, count(list_num)
    FROM pair_candidates WHERE list_num != ""
    GROUP BY group_num""").fetchall() })
print(groups)
```

This returns as expected:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0}
```